# SUBSTRING related problem

Tags: sql

I have string type abc_01, abcd_01 or 02 now I want the substring up to _ ie abc_,abcd_ etc. I am using db2 as400.  Please suggest the processing through RIGHT or LEFT function.

Answer (score 0):

use SUBSTRING and charindex as suggested in your duplicate other post.